# excel full screen disable when minimize and maximize

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have below code for getting full screen view for the Excel workbook. But when I minimize the workbook and Maximize, full screen feature automatically disabling. I need full screen in all condition for this workbook. Please suggest.

```
Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
Application.CommandBars("Full Screen").Enabled = False
'Disable the Esc key.
Application.OnKey "{ESC}", ""
```

Comment: Where is this code being called? It won't be easy for us to determine why you're experiencing this behavior without that information.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for me:

In your workbook -> Event Windows Resize
Not necessary disable ESC key in this situation

```
Private Sub Workbook_WindowResize(ByVal Wn As Window)
   Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'this sub is automatically called on opening the workbook

Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
'the active window is expanded to the biggest size available 
End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain, in plain English, how this solves the problem.

Comment: @user3671568 Please let me know if this answer helped you. (: .. alright, editing now

Comment: Thanks for You help Tom. But sorry it's not working. please find below the Code which i have entered for Workbook open                        Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Range("K11").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("K13").Select
Selection.ClearContents
With ActiveWindow
.DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = False
.DisplayVerticalScrollBar = False
.DisplayHeadings = False
End With
Application.CommandBars.ActiveMenuBar.Enabled = False
Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
Application.CommandBars("Full Screen").Enabled = False
' Disable the Esc key.
Application.OnKey "{ESC}", ""